# Matplotlib - having strange errors/issues which trying to plot multiple bars

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

fairly noobish here, I have data in a pandas dataframe that has data that has people's score (out of 5) to various things. I'm trying to use matplotlib to plot bars horizontally, 3 bars next to each other for each person on one question (on y) with the scores on x. According to the official docs and other sources, I just need to add some numbers to y to move the bars over a bit, but it's giving me a strange error, saying it needs to be a string. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The data looks like this:

```
name  thing_1  thing_2  thing_3
John  4        3        1
Jane  5        2        4
Bob   3        3        4
```

and the code

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,10))
y1 = data.iloc[:,1:].columns
x1 = data.iloc[0:1,1:].sum(axis=0)

y2 = data.iloc[:,1:].columns
x2 = data.iloc[1:2,1:].sum(axis=0)

y3 = data.iloc[:,1:].columns
x3 = data.iloc[2:,1:].sum(axis=0)

width = 0.3

ax.barh(y,x,width,align='center')
ax.barh(y+0.3,x,width,align='center')
ax.barh(y+0.6,x,width,align='center')

plt.xlabel('Score')
plt.ylabel('Bodypart')
plt.title('Body part total score')
plt.legend(data['name'].values)
plt.show()
```

and the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-a7f65a43c075> in <module>()
     45 
     46 ax.barh(y,x,width,align='center')
---> 47 ax.barh(y+0.3,x,width,align='center')
     48 ax.barh(y+0.6,x,width,align='center')
     49 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __add__(self, other)
   2684 
   2685     def __add__(self, other):
-> 2686         return Index(np.array(self) + other)
   2687 
   2688     def __radd__(self, other):

TypeError: must be str, not float
```

Comment: Obviously, you set apply an array of strings to the y-positions of your barh-graph, instead of the position values you'd like to achieve. The name-array should be put into the `tick-label`kwarg of `barh`.

Answer (score 0):

Just after patching to get your code run:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,10))
y = np.arange(1, 4)
names = data.iloc[:,1:].columns

x = data.iloc[0:1,1:].sum(axis=0)
x2 = data.iloc[1:2,1:].sum(axis=0)
x3 = data.iloc[2:,1:].sum(axis=0)

width = 0.3

ax.barh(y,x,width,align='center', tick_label=names)
ax.barh(y+0.3,x2,width,align='center')
ax.barh(y+0.6,x3,width,align='center')

plt.xlabel('Score')
plt.ylabel('Bodypart')
plt.title('Body part total score')
plt.legend(data['name'].values)
plt.show()
```

However, I think this should be optimizable...

EDIT: And here's how. Import your data such that `name` is not a 4th column but the dataframe's index:

```
df = data.drop(columns='name')

df
   thing_1  thing_2  thing_3
0        4        3        1
1        5        2        4
2        3        3        4

df.index=data.name

df
      thing_1  thing_2  thing_3
name                           
John        4        3        1
Jane        5        2        4
Bob         3        3        4
```

Then you can simply do

```
df.plot(kind='barh')
```

and get

[image]